# iOS static library with same third party lib cause duplicate symbol error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I make a static library `libA.a` that required `SDWebImage`, and I want to add `libA.a` to **ProjectB**, which already has `SDWebImage`, then cause `duplicate symbol error`.

UPDATE: I can't just remove `SDWebImage` from `ProjectB`, the both `SDWebImage` are different versions, and `SDWeImage` in `ProjectB` has make some custom changes.

Is there any way that I can use same named third party in both static library and project?

Thanks.

Comment: you could just remove `SDWebImage` from **ProjectB**, because it is already in `libA.a`

Comment: @JeanLuc I can't remove SD from ProjectB because SD in ProjectB has make some custom change, and version of both SD not the same.

Comment: oh, in that case i would renamed the patched SDWebImage class

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue with using two third-party libraries. I resolved this by removing `all_load` from "Other Linker Flags" in build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this similar question](http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/) and [Avoiding duplicate symbol issues when using common utilities within a static library](http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/)

In short, this can be resolved by adding a series of -DOldSymbol=NewSymbol flags to the ‘Other C Flags’ build setting of ProjectB.